# How do I populate a table with dates based on a date that a user has selected with angular ui datepicker?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I want to be able to populate a table with 24 days, each incremented a day ahead from the previous. So for instance, if 7/1/2017 was chosen I would want to populate the table with 7/2/2017, 7/3/2017, 7/4/2017...7/5/2017.

I was previously using Jquery's datepicker and got everything working by doing this:

```
<p id="dateStuff">
  Date: <br />
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</p>
```

Script:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 24; i++) {
  var result = new Date(currentDateString);
  var someFormattedDate = 0;
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + 1);
  var dd = result.getDate();
  var mm = result.getMonth() + 1;
  if (mm < 10) {
    someFormattedDate = '0'+ mm + '/' + dd + '/' + y;
  }
  else {
    someFormattedDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + y;
  }
  currentDateString = someFormattedDate;
  document.getElementById("date" + i).appendChild(document.createTextNode(currentDateString));
}
```

Now I am trying to work with the angular ui datepicker (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker) and i'm struggling to figure out how to get it to work similarly.

Here are snippets of my current code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="cpDate">Date</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="inputStartDate" type="text" ng-model="sc.model.date" class="form-control" ng-required="true"
      ng-focus="isDatePickerStartOpened=true"
      uib-datepicker-popup="MM-dd-yyyy"
      datepicker-options="datepickerOptions"
      is-open="isDatePickerStartOpened"
      close-text="Close"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default form-control" ng-click="sc.showDatePickerStart($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
var vm = this;
vm.model = {
  date: new Date(),
};
alert(vm.model.date.toString().substring(4, 15));
```

I'm stuck because when the alert shows me the date in the form of Jul 19 2017 instead of 7/19/2017. I also do not know how to get the month, day, etc and add to it like I did previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it looks like you are using `sc.model.date` instead of `vm.model.date` in your template.

Second, Angular has a built-in date filter that allows you to easily format dates (be sure to inject the `$filter` provider into controller the same way you inject `$scope`):

```
var formattedDate = $filter('date')(vm.model.date, 'MM/dd/YYYY');
alert(formattedDate);
```

Third. Working in Angular vs working with JQuery or plain JS is all about the model and not about the DOM. You don't use selectors to target DOM objects. Instead you work from the model first. So just concentrate on getting an array of date objects you want:

```
vm.dates = [vm.model.date];

for(var i=1; i<=24; i++) {
  vm.dates.push(addDays(vm.model.date, i));
}

function addDays(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
  return $filter('date')(result, 'MM/dd/yy');
}
```

So now you have an array with all the dates you want. You can use Angular's `ng-repeat` to display your table:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr><td>Date</td></tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="day in vm.dates">
    <td>{{day}}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```